# ¿Por qué en un tabactivity se ejecuta el codigo de 2 fragments a la vez?

Tags: android

Buenas tardes a todos!

Soy nuevo en esto de programación android y tengo una app en la que estoy implementando un tabactivity, el problema es que cuando corro la app, se ejecuta el código java de la primera actividad y de la segunda también y cuando me posiciono en el segundo tab, se ejecuta el código java de la 3ra actividad.

Puse un Toast en el código java de cada tab para verificar que se estaba mezclando el código.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;


public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {

String NombreUsuario, Medico;
int IdPaciente;

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new 
    SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if(bundle!=null){
        NombreUsuario = (String) bundle.get("NombreUsuario");
        IdPaciente = (int) bundle.get("IdPaciente");
        Medico = (String) bundle.get("Medico");
    }

    }



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_principal, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.actualizar) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Busqueda tabBusqueda = new Busqueda();
                return tabBusqueda;
            case 1:
                Turnos tabTurnos = new Turnos();
                return tabTurnos;
            case 2:
                Citas tabCitas = new Citas();
                return tabCitas;

            default:
                return null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Búsqueda";
            case 1:
                return "Mis Turnos";
            case 2:
                return "Mis Citas";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Mejor utiliza fragmentos y haz el agregado de fragmentos dinamico.

Comment: Estoy utilizando fragmentos y los llamo de acuerdo a la posición que esta el tab.